# Using Scala.JS within Grunt or Gulp

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, scala.js

Has anyone used Scala JS in a pure Grunt or Gulp developer workflow? How did you set up the tools to work together?

The ideal answer would touch on developer workflow, how Javascript dependencies were managed and how the output packages were fed back into package managers for upstream inclusion.

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: If you want to use external tools to instrument Scala.js, you might want to have a look at the [CLI tools](http://www.scala-js.org/downloads.html) we provide.

Comment: Prorably, the easier direction to look at would be to run **sbt** from Gulp/Grunt...